# Mensajes vacíos en yahoo

Tags: php, mail

Recibo mensajes de una api en php, pero cuando el destinatario es de yahoo, el mensaje llega con todos los estilos de CSS pero sin texto.

Comment: Adjunta el código de envío censurando lo necesario. Pero a simple vista y predicción, no has creado el `AltBody`. Imagino que tu body es Html puro más CSS, pero en caso de que dicho correo no acepte HTML, debes agregar `AltBody`... quedo a espera de código para confirmar esta teoría.

Comment: No tengo mucho acceso al código de donde se envían los correos, pero no se si sea eso, porque en outlook y gmail si recibo los correos correctamente

Comment: No digo que los recibas mal, solo que no está contenido el caso en donde el correo no acepte html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La plataforma de yahoo hacía que el texto que llegaba en el mensaje de html tuviera un font-size de 0.
Una vez que forcé el tamaño de la letra, los mensajes ya podían verse correctamente

Answer (score 0):

Lo más probable es que el problema ocurra al no contener el caso en que el correo destinatario no acepte formato HTML.
Para contener el problema, se usa `AltBody`, el cual sería el texto sin formato HTML. Este mismo, no reemplaza el original, a menos que sea necesario.

Te dejo un ejemplo del uso de `AltBody`, para que te hagas una idea.

```
//Mensaje HTML correspondiente
$Mail->Body("<p>El Mensaje con HTML<p>");

//Mensaje alternativo que no soporte html
$Mail->AltBody("El mensaje SIN HTML");
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, ya ví cual era el problema, yahoo pone por defecto el font-size en 0 de los textos en html, así que hay que hardcodearle el font-size para que el mensaje se vea

Comment: Si encontraste la solución a tu problema, por favor, agrégala como respuesta